# Gunicorn times out even when creating a new app

Tags: python, django, configuration, gunicorn, foreman

I found this question with similar output: [Gunicorn workers timeout no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555669/gunicorn-workers-timeout-no-matter-what). It's solution does not work.

~~~

So when I run `foreman start web` I get the following output:

```
17:53:46 web.1  | started with pid 31807
17:53:46 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:53:46 -0400] [31807] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
17:53:46 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:53:46 -0400] [31807] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (31807)
17:53:46 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:53:46 -0400] [31807] [INFO] Using worker: sync
17:53:46 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:53:46 -0400] [31810] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31810
17:54:26 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:54:26 -0400] [31807] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31810)
17:54:26 web.1  | [2015-06-26 21:54:26 +0000] [31810] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 31810)
17:54:26 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:54:26 -0400] [31821] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31821
17:54:57 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:54:57 -0400] [31807] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31821)
17:54:57 web.1  | [2015-06-26 21:54:57 +0000] [31821] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 31821)
17:54:58 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:54:58 -0400] [31831] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31831
17:55:29 web.1  | [2015-06-26 17:55:29 -0400] [31807] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31831)
...
```

and so on.

Loading it in a browser just connects and times out.

Procfile: `web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -`

`wsgi.py`:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gettingstarted.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise


application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

I will update this question with more information as time goes on.

EDIT 4: Reverted other edits, question revamp.

*Days later...* I created an entirely new app with django-admin.py, a new procfile, virtualenv, git, requirements.txt, and updated virtualenv, but when I start the app it ***still*** times out.

What's going on with my computer?

EDIT 5: Anybody that figures out exactly what went wrong gets the bounty. I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm trying not to post a wall of text, but I am trying to give just the right amount of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, but it seemed to be with my internet connection, since it still timed out. I get an Internal Server Error now. If you have a similar problem, you may want to check your internet.