# Gunicorn gevent worker logging issues

Tags: python, logging, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, gevent

I have a `gunicorn` server running with 1 worker. I user the logging module during the request. None of them appear in stdout.
I know that gevent workers monkey patch all so I would assume any loggin done during the request should appear on the mainthread stdout.

The app parse to gunicorn is the application wsgi from django.

`gunicorn -c gunicorn.py core.wsgi:application`

In `gunicorn.py` I have:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8080'
backlog = 2048
workers = 1
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 60
keepalive = 2

proc_name = None

def post_fork(server, worker):
    server.log.info("Worker spawned (pid: %s)", worker.pid)


def pre_fork(server, worker):
    pass


def pre_exec(server):
    server.log.info("Forked child, re-executing.")


def when_ready(server):
    server.log.info("Server is ready. Spawning workers")


def worker_int(worker):
    worker.log.info("Worker received INT or QUIT signal")

    import threading, sys, traceback
    id2name = dict([(th.ident, th.name) for th in threading.enumerate()])
    code = []
    for thread_id, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
        code.append("\n# Thread: %s(%d)" % (id2name.get(thread_id, ""),
                                            thread_id))
        for filename, line_no, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename,
                                                        line_no, name))
            if line:
                code.append("  %s" % (line.strip()))
    worker.log.debug("\n".join(code))


def worker_abort(worker):
    worker.log.info("Worker received SIGABRT signal")
```

Within on of the request functions I simply put

```
import logging
logging.error('test'))
```

It only executes this log after the worker has finished its request.
And some of the other logs don't even show up like so.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test_logger'))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.error('test')
```

If you need anything else from me to possibly help me towards resolving this issue ask away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply needed to add this to the gunicorn.py

```
errorlog = '-'
loglevel = 'info'
accesslog = '-'
```